Is it possible to enhance search engine optimization in Flutter Web Projects with Next.js Integration
I have been looking into different ways to integrate my flutter web into another framework to make overall integration SEO friendly as much as possible. This way I want to introduce blogs in my website to improve its SEO.
I just saw an article on Medium which mentioned that we can integrate flutter web into next.js but I couldn't find any more suitable details about this integration over the internet.
I have placed my flutter web build inside public/flutter_web_project folder in next.js project and below is how I am accessing the flutter web and running it in browser.
'use client'
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Home = ({ isCrawler }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isCrawler) {
      // Load Flutter web app for regular users
      window.location.href = '/flutter_web_project/index.html';
    }
  }, [isCrawler]);

  return (
    <div>
      {isCrawler ? (
        // Provide SEO-friendly content for crawlers
        <div>
          <h1>My Flutter Web App</h1>
          <p>Here's some content that's important for SEO...</p>
          {/* More SEO-friendly content */}
        </div>
      ) : (
        // Regular users will be redirected to Flutter web app
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

The above is somehow working but I just want to know that
1 - Can this be proved helpful in enhancing SEO of flutter web by introducing SEO friendly content in next.js like blog section in my case?
2 - Will search engines like Google like this approach or it may put a bad impact on them?
